# When can you interchange $\mathbb{E}$ with the limit in a stochastic process?

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose that $(X(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is a stochastic process, with $p-$finite moments. Then is it posible to do this change?

\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\vert X(t)\vert^p]=\mathbb{E}[\lim_{t\to \infty}\vert X(t)\vert^p]=\mathbb{E}[\vert \lim_{t\to \infty} X(t)\vert^p].
\end{align}

The second equality I think holds as $x\mapsto x^p$ and the norms are continuous maps. However, I am having trouble finding a convincing argument to justify the first one. For example in the case where $X(t)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_t,\sigma_t).$

Also, on a side note:
When I think of the moments of a $d-$dimensional stochastic process, can I think about them as individual entries each one with the one-dimensional case? Does it depend on the distribution? For example, for the multivariate normal distribution, can I say that if $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ is a $d-$dimensional random vector, then $\mathbb{E}[\vert X \vert ^p]=(\mathbb{E}[\vert X_1 \vert ^p], \dots, \mathbb{E}[\vert X_d \vert ^p])^T$, where each $X_i\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: No it's not. You need to verify or justify this equation e.g. by dominated or monotone convergence theorem.

For example consider for $p=1$ the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\Bbb P) = ([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ and define $X_t: \Omega \to \Bbb R$ by $$X_t(\omega) := t\cdot 1_{\left(0,\frac{1}{t}\right)}(\omega)$$

Then $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\vert X(t)\vert^p] = \lim_{t\to \infty} t\cdot \frac{1}{t} = 1$$ but $$\lim_{t\to \infty}\vert X(t)\vert^p = 0$$ and so $$\mathbb{E}[\lim_{t\to \infty}\vert X(t)\vert^p] = 0$$

For your second question:

Indeed if $X = (X_1,\ldots, X_d)$ it holds $E[X] = (E[X_1], \ldots, E[X_d])$.
But: $$\mathbb{E}[\vert X \vert ^p]=(\mathbb{E}[\vert X_1 \vert ^p], \dots, \mathbb{E}[\vert X_d \vert ^p])^T$$ makes no sense at all because $|X|^p$ is not a vector anymore but a real-valued random variable.
So use the definition of absolut value to get an expression depending on $X_i$.